# SolrJ addDateRangeFacet and addFacetPivotField

Tags: solr, solrj

my document looks like below:

```
id.  category.    sub-category.  date
1.   A.           subA.          2017-08-09
2.   B.           subB.          2017-08-09
3.   A.           subA2.         2017-08-09
3.   A.           subA2.         2017-08-10
```

i would like to do addDateRangeFacet on date field with gap = 1day, also i would want to facet on both category and sub-category field

so i the result will look like:

```
category : {
   A: {
     subCategory: {
       subA: {
         bucket: 2017-08-09 count 1
       }
       subA2: {
         bucketCount: 2017-08-09 count 1
         bucketCount: 2017-08-10 count 1
       }
     }
   }
   B: {
     subCategory: {
       subB: {
         bucket: 2017-08-09 count 1
       }
     }
   }
}
```

is it possible to use solrJ to do something like above? i tried to combine the two method i mentioned but it does not work

Comment: The [JSON Facet API should allow you to specify multilevel (i.e. pivot) facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/json-facet-api.html) for that - there are examples for SolrJ in the reference guide as well (click `SolrJ` instead of `curl` on the example). See if that solves it and update your question with any issues you run into.

Comment: @MatsLindh yeah the above should work, for certain reason I have to use solrj 6.*, i checked 6.* documentation, couldn't find something similar to that

Comment: Most of the JSON Facet API became supported in late 5.x and 6.x-releases, so they should work - however, they might require a different use in SolrJ if they don't have the utility classes (i.e. JSON-requests).